# How to create a link for List's NewForm.aspx that opens in Modal Dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a custom list, and I want to create a direct link on the home page which points directly to adding a new item aka NewForm.aspx

So, I edited the page and add a link i.e. "Click Here" => (http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx)

But this link redirects to a new page which has the new form! I don't want that!

I want that if user clicks on "Click Here", then, The NewForm.aspx opens in Modal Dialog. I read that there is a way to accomplish this by using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog("URL");`  but how can I add the page? The link web part nor the hyperlink on the page will not accept that.

Could you please guide me ?

I tried `<input type="button" value="Register" name="Go" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog("http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx");" />`

But it didn't work, besides, I wish to have the link as a text and not a button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very close but you can simply use a bit of html and javascript:

```
<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog("http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx");return false;" href="">Display Item </a>
```

above explained:

Html part is the '    ' tag. this is for putting html links on a page:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

For the javascript part we use `onclick` event (when a user clicks the hyperlink link). Within the quote marks you denote that your using javascript by the term `javascript:` once you have that part you can use any function or direct javascript code you want like doing an alert/messagebox  `alert("hello");`. Most important is that you use `return false;` so that the onclick event is not expecting a value to postback that will refresh the page. the default `href` can be kept blank as we dont need to use it but is needed due to html requiring it so setting it to blank is more than enough  `""` .

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the following code within a Script Editor / Content Editor:

```
 <script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
var options = {
    url: pageUrl,
    title: 'Title of the Dialog',
    allowMaximize: false,
    showClose: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}

</script> 
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://SharePointSite/Lists/WebEvents/NewForm.aspx');">New Form</a>
```

Note :

- To show `Maximize button` set `allowMaximize: true`,

OutPut:

[image]

Check also the detail steps that matched with your situation at [Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. I tried in content editor webpart and it works.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('/sites/.../Lists/TestList/NewForm.aspx',null,500,250,'Add new Item')">New Item</a></p>
```