# Floating button to submit new list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, client-object-model

I am trying to find information on creating a button that I can have "float" at the bottom right or left of a SharePoint page that when clicked will open a dialog box for a new list item to be saved.

I found this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190517/how-to-create-a-link-for-lists-newform-aspx-that-opens-in-modal-dialog) that does a good job of showing how to create a link that opens a modal dialog box to submit list items.

The missing part is I want the link to be a button that isn't located in a web-part zone. I want to be able to have the button at the bottom of the user's screen even when scrolling. Here is an image of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example]

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using css and applying

```
button{
    position: fixed;
}
```

to your button along with the other css you used to place it at bottom right. It doesnt matter whether it is in web part zone or not. CSS will be applied at page level.