# SharePoint web part view

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, list-form

Is there anyway and is it possible to input a web part onto a SharePoint page but display the "NewForm.aspx"?

Currently the only views that are available to display are "Current View", "All Items" and "Summary View".

I just need to add a web that shows the view of when you add a new item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint on-premise, there are couple of ways you can try:

1. Create & customize page using SP designer
2. Using Iframe in content editor/script editor web part which links to `NewForm.aspx` page of list.
3. Using Page Viewer Web part

You can find more information about above options at: [How to embed newform.aspx on a page?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3854f056-2ca0-430d-90c0-e5f418b3184a/how-to-embed-newformaspx-on-a-page-?)

Another option is to use SharePoint modal dialog, which show new item form of list on click of button.

**References**:

1. [How to open New List Item Form in modal dialog in a SharePoint 2010 page from different site collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384513/how-to-open-new-list-item-form-in-modal-dialog-in-a-sharepoint-2010-page-from-di)
2. [How to create a link for List's NewForm.aspx that opens in Modal Dialog?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190517/how-to-create-a-link-for-lists-newform-aspx-that-opens-in-modal-dialog/265937)

**Note**:

New item form URL will always be in below format, you can use it while trying above ways:

```
<siteUrl>/Lists/<listName>/NewForm.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a page that shows only the "new item" form, you can just use the NewForm.aspx page (/NewForm.aspx). You can try to add a new item to the list and grab the URL from browser address bar.
Then, you can add a link to it in the quick launch menu or wherever your users are expecting to find navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the key distinctions here, that the other answers do not explicitly point out, is that there is a difference between list **Views** and list **Forms**.

Lists come with three default **Forms**, the "New" form, the "Display" form, and the "Edit" form.  Forms:

- Show only the data for a *single* list item.
- Show the data in a two column table, where each field/column is represented as a *row*, and the field/column names are in the left hand column, and the value of that field for that particular list item is in the right hand column, either displayed just as text (in the Display form), or in editable controls (for the "New" or "Edit" forms).

List **Views**, on the other hand:

- Show data from *multiple* list items at the same time
- Are organized in a multi-column table, where each list *item* is represented as a row in the table, and the fields/columns of the list are represented as the *columns* of that table.

"All Items" is the main default ***view*** of any list. You can also create custom views that apply filtering and sorting, and define which fields/columns you actually want to see as the columns of the table shown in that view.

The screen shot posted by the OP is the web part property pane of a **List View Web Part**.  This web part is used to show **views**.  If there were any custom views set up on that list, they would be available as options in the highlighted drop-down, along with "All Items", "Summary View" and "Current View".

However, the "New" form, being that it is a **Form** and not a **View**, is naturally not included in the options for the List View Web Part.

The other answers here provide some good options if the OP is looking to get users to the "New" form for the list from somewhere other than going straight to the list and clicking "new item".

- Copy the URL of the "New" form for that list and use it in a link on another page somewhere.
- Figure out how to expose that form through an iFrame (or some other means) on a different page.

However, you are not going to be able to select and show the "New" form (or either of the other forms) using the List View Web Part.